# Set Image on Left side of EditText in Android

Tags: android, drawable, android-edittext

I am having one contact form in which I would like to add some icons to my edit text for a better look. I want to create EditText something like below.

[image]

I have EditText like below. And I got the result something like. I want the image to be absolutely on the left side as it is in the above image. I know that internally EditText is using Nine Patch image and i think that is why the result is some what different. Can anyone know how to resolve this?

[image]

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="51dip"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/name_icon_edittext" />
```

Comment: Did you try by setting android:paddingLeft property.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of using `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/name_icon_edittext"`, create separate`ImageView` for the `name_icon`.
This way you have more control on placing it on the `layout`

**Note:** I am assuming your `layout` is `RelativeLayout`

Comment: yes my layout is relative layout...Thanks for your suggestion but if i create Imageview instead of drawable left than how it will be useful in terms of more control? Can you please tell me how it is beneficial to the app? Is it related to performance or something

Comment: I hope you check your layout on few different resolution screen and verify it, else if you need some tuning you could set the padding and margin in more flexibly way like I mention above

Answer (score 15):

if you want to add some space between you text and image then use'drawablePadding' property in xml

```
android:drawablePadding="10dp"
```

here is complete example how to use in edittext in xml file

```
             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_left"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `android:drawablePadding="10dp"` property in the xml file. 
There's no need to create separate imagview for the icon.

Comment: I just fixed the formatting (the grey background behind `android:drawable...`) There's nothing wrong with your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit old, but for future reference maybe:

I would do a 9-patch image myself with the appearance you want, keeping the proportions and all but the icon, so you can add it yourself (and reuse the background) with `drawableLeft` property of `EditText`. That way only the middle part of the image will be stretched but the rest will stay the same.