# How can use Image In editText Android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: username]

[image: password]

How can i use above  image inside of  edit text Android?

Comment: You can create above image as nine patch then you can set as background directly.

Comment: use android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img" and customized accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "drawableLeft" attribute of `EditText`. For example:

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_user"
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft

Answer (score 1):

user this in your edittext

```
<EditText
...     
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_icon" />
```

Another way is that you can create ImageView for that icon. This way you have more control on placing it

Comment: For that create a separate image view for icon This way you have more control on placing it on the layout see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444320/set-image-on-left-side-of-edittext-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Add left paddding and set EditText background to your drawable:

```
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/my_icon"
```