# Android layerlist drawable

Tags: android, drawable, layer-list

I am creating a login layout for an app.For the background of the LinearLayout(id=@+id/lgn_lyt) I tried to make it look like the image below.It looks fine in design editor,but in the device it look weird.The drawable I used is a vector image.Is it because of the vector image I used it coding mistake in the layerlist?Expecting your answers....

login_lyt.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lgn_lyt"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/usr_nm_lyt_hght"
        android:background="@drawable/usr_lyt_bg"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/usrnm_lyt_mrgn_left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/usrnm_lyt_mrgn_right"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/usrnm_lyt_mrgn_top">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/usrnme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/usr_hnt"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/usrnm_mrgn_left"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/psswrd_lyt"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/usr_nm_lyt_hght"
        android:background="@drawable/psswrd_lyt_bg"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/usrnm_lyt_mrgn_left"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/usrnm_lyt_mrgn_right"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/usrnm_lyt_mrgn_top">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/psswrd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/psswrd_hnt"
            android:inputType="textWebPassword"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/usrnm_mrgn_left"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/usrnm_lyt_mrgn_top"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
             />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

usr_lyt_bg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        >
        <shape
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:shape="rectangle"
            android:thickness="2dp">
            <solid android:color="#10000000"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:drawable="@drawable/user"
        android:left="15dp"
        >
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In design editor:
[image]

In Device:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444320/set-image-on-left-side-of-edittext-in-android

Comment: Why does it look different from one in design editor?

Comment: @jobin actually you are doing it wrong. maybe there is something wrong with design editor but the device is showing the right result.

Comment: What could be the problem with the design editor

Answer (score 0):

for image you can use "android:drawableLeft="" " property in EditText.
No need to use background property in LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

If they dont provide any function other than design why not just add the images using Drawable-left = myImage  with the appropriate padding?

Answer (score 0):

change your layout like this: you need to use android:drawableStart: in your edittext not as a background. Your device is showing the right results.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lgn_lyt"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/usr_nm_lyt_hght"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/usrnm_lyt_mrgn_left"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/usrnm_lyt_mrgn_right"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/usrnm_lyt_mrgn_top">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usrnme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/usr_hnt"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/usr_lyt_bg"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/usr_lyt_bg"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/usrnm_mrgn_left"
        />
       </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/psswrd_lyt"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/usr_nm_lyt_hght"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/usrnm_lyt_mrgn_left"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/usrnm_lyt_mrgn_right"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/usrnm_lyt_mrgn_top">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/psswrd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/psswrd_hnt"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/psswrd_lyt_bg"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/psswrd_lyt_bg"
        android:inputType="textWebPassword"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/usrnm_mrgn_left"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/usrnm_lyt_mrgn_top"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```